# C# using foreach on a list and binding those results

Tags: c#, list

I have a list that can be anywhere from 2-10 items. I need to loop through that list and assign each one to an appropriate spot, based on how many are in the list.

I know that the first item in my list will always be in the first position. But I need to go through the list and do something like this if I have say, 4 items.

item 2 == list item 2
item 3 == list item 3
item 4 == last list item

I'm thinking something like this? Any thoughts?

```
var count = myList.Count;
            var lastStop = myList.Count - 1;
            if (myList.Count == 2)
            {
                //dosomething here
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (item xxx in myList)
                {
                    //
                }
            }
```

Editing in attempt to clarify.

Stamping a pdf with a fixed number of fields. Call them Field1 through Field10.

So what I need to do is always stamp Field1 with List[0], this will always be true. The remainder of the list needs to be assigned in order to the fields, with the list having varying lengths. For example:

If there are two items in the list:
Field1 = List[0]
Field2 = List[1]

There is a shipper and a receiver, but possibly multiple points in between. So I need the receiver to always be written to the PDF last, with the multiple stops between the first field, and the last field.

Does that help?

Comment: what do you mean when you say assign to an appropriate spot? do you mean you have something in the UI you are assigning it to?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so it should be tagged as such

Comment: Sorry, I'm putting these into a pdf using the itextsharp library. So I have a fixed number of fields. Like field1, field2, etc.

Comment: you need a For loop instead sounds like

Comment: Please stress what you're actually up to.

Comment: I read it twice and still don't understand

Comment: So, is there an "Item Number" property in whatever object is in your list?  How do you determine an items "appropriate spot?"

Comment: its gonna be like getting array to list with bindind ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so based on the comments, there's going to be something like a Name property with field1, field2, field3, etc, and you need to sort by the field number.  Correct?

```
var newArray = new WhateverObject[myList.Count];
foreach (var whatever in myList)
{
    int i = Convert.ToInt32( whatever.Name.Replace("field", "") );
    newArray[i] = whatever;
}
```

Something like that.